# Can we add TSR in .lib library?

Tags: c, dos

I want to add TSR in my .lib file is it possible..?
I am developing this project on ms-dos system in C language.
So I need TSR for multi-tasking.
So please help me, If possible to use TSR in .lib library.

Comment: In order to terminate and stay resident, the *thing* must be a program (.COM or .EXE in MS/DOS). The relevant code can come from a .lib, provided it is linked to produce an executable. Long story short: I cannot really understand what you are asking here.

Comment: ... why are you using DOS?

Comment: TSRs aren't some magic ingredient you can add that will give MS-DOS applications the ability multitask. TSRs are a kind of program that if they do offer some sort ability to multitask, must implement multitasking themselves.